# How to check the character appearance in EditText?

Tags: android

I wonder :

I want to create an action when I start typing in Edittext ( when the first character appear)

I googled for that, but I couldn't find anything?

I have on idea. Help me, please. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Use `editText.AddTextChangedListener()`. You can check in [`beforeTextChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#beforeTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) whether the existing text is empty and the new text to be added is not empty.

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s) && after > 0) {
        // new text added to empty text field
    }
}
```